# How to build a Job candidate prediction model

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, natural-language

I am currently learning about data science and I wanted to deal with real-world data in order to improve my abilities.

I have the following csv files, the parantheses are the column names.

Candidates (Candidate Id, University Name, University Department, End Year, City),

Accepted Candidates (Candidate Id, Job Id)

Applications (Candidate Id, Job Id)

Jop Postings (Job Id, Job Explanation, Qualifications, Location, Sector, Position)

Candidate Experience (Candidate Id, Sector Name, Position, Work Duration, Job Explanation)

Candidate Skills (Candidate Id, Skill)

Using these data, I want to match Job Id's with Candidate Ids and predict which candidate got which job.

I am thinking about a bag-of-words approach with NLP tools and create a link between the words that inside the candidate profiles and jobs. Is there a better way? Can I use NNs? What approach should I consider? I'd be really happy if you give me some keywords for me to research and implement.

Comment: This seems like one of those ethically bad ideas—or at least, close enough to one that it’s risky. If you’re interested in exploring NLP, there are plenty of other things available to experiment with.

Comment: No personal data is given in the dataset tho.